# Use HSQLDB in JBoss5.1

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, hsqldb

In my current project, I use HSQLDB 2.0 and JBoss5.1 .

Currently I am starting the HSQLDB server from command prompt as :

`java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server  --database.0 file:hmc`

and connect to HSQLDB from datasource defined in deploy folder of jBoss.

But now I do not want to start HSQLDB externally but would like to start it when jBoss starts.

Is it possible to perform such action, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply added HSQLDB startup script to the jBoss startup script.